# Generators Trees in a Tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

My question is very short:

How many spanning trees have a tree?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove one edge form a tree, it becomes disconnected. Hence a spanning connected subgraph must containt all egdes, hence the only spanning tree of a tree $T$ is $T$. The answer is 1, hence.